# How should I replace PApplet MouseEvent since it is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, processing, interactive

I've been playing around and trying to learn Processing 3.0+ for JavaScript using their fun little IDE.

I found some code searching around for a way to detect mouse double clicks and I found how to do this, which works great - BUT - the IDE is warning me that PApplet MouseEvent (which has the getClickCount method) is deprecated.

Can anyone help me find what replaced MouseEvent so I can use that more properly instead?  I've really tried searching around and I can find no reference to any replacement.

```
void setup(){
  size(1200, 750);
  background(200);
}

void draw(){
  stroke(0);
}

void mousePressed() { 
  if (mouseButton == LEFT) { 
     if (mouseEvent.getClickCount()==2) {
       fill (255, 0, 0, 128);
       ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
     } else {
       fill (0, 255, 0, 128);
       ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
     }    
  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) { 
    fill (0, 0, 255, 128);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the `MouseEvent` class is deprecated?

The [documentation](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/event/MouseEvent.html) mentions that the `getClickCount` function is deprecated, but it does not say that the class itself is deprecated.

According to that same documentation, you should use `getCount` instead.

By the way, it looks like you're using Processing in Java mode, not JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting!

At the bottom of the IDE it says "The field PApplet.mouseEvent is deprecated", but when I hover over getClickCount, the tooltip says "The method getClickCount from the type MouseEvent is deprecated"

So... I tried changing it to getCount, which still works great, *but* mouseEvent still gets the yellow error underscore and the "The field PApplet.mouseEvent is deprecated" message.  

Before, both had the underscore, now only mouseEvent itself gets it.

Comment: Also, LOL, yes, I see I've been working in Java mode...  er...  Oops? I guess I'm going to learn the differences between the two now.  (I tried to upvote you but I'm new here and my votes don't count yet)